# Three Days Grace guitar distortion tone

Tags: software, tone, distortion

How do I get Three Days Grace guitar distortion sound in Garageband or Logic. What are the other ways to reproduce the exact sound used in their riffs?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Here's the song's link: [Three Days Grace - Break](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4VCpTZye10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should find the best sound setting on your own.
To me their sound is closer to overdrive than distortion.
And Barry Stock uses Triaxis preamp, maybe this'll help you